# Language Change on click of button - Fragment issue

Tags: android, fragment

In **Fragment** there is **Button** which I have used to switch between **languages**.But when I click that **Button**, to switch between languages ,it does not change the **language**.

```
 Locale locale = new Locale(MyPrefences.LANGUAGE_TO_LOAD);
   if (locale.equals("ar"))
   {
       locale = new Locale(MyPrefences.LANGUAGE_TO_LOAD);
       Locale.setDefault(locale);
       MyPrefences.SET_VALUES(getApplicationContext());
   }
   else
   {
       locale = new Locale(MyPrefences.LANGUAGE_TO_LOAD);
       Locale.setDefault(locale);
       MyPrefences.SET_VALUES(getApplicationContext());
   }

   Resources resources = mContext.getResources();

Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
configuration.locale = locale;

resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());


}
```

I have used the same code in another application in that I have used the **Activity** so it works fine 
But now I'm using **Fragment** now it's not working 
I'm stuck please give suggestion to overcome form it

Comment: change getApplicationContext() to getActivity()

Comment: Its not showing getActivity() as I have used Fragment

Comment: We have to use getActivity() for fragment  if not showing then restart android studio

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `mContext` is not null.
you can get context in the fragment from any of the views.
 `view.getContext()` and use this to get resources and change the config.